# Call to undefined method Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor::setUrl()

Tags: magento2, customer, redirect-url

In my custom module to displaying the button on **customer edit page** (`adminhtml`), when hit the **custom button** it will call `my custom controller` after executed again I am redirecting to **customer edit page**. Here My custom controller is called, but when it redirecting Error is throwing.

> Error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor::setUrl() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magentoee21\app\code\SR\StackExchange\Controller\Adminhtml\Stackexchange\Customer.php
>   on line 22 Call Stack

**and my code is:**

**root/app/code/SR/StackExchange/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="custom_button" xsi:type="string">SR\StackExchange\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\CustomButton</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</form>
```

**root/app/code/SR/StackExchange/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/CustomButton.php**

```
<?php

namespace SR\StackExchange\Block\Adminhtml\Edit;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

class CustomButton extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\GenericButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {

        if($this->getCustomerId()){
            return [
                'label' => __('Custom Button'),
                'on_click' => sprintf("location.href = '%s';", $this->getCustomerUrl()),
                'class' => 'action-secondary',
                'sort_order' => 10
            ];
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get URL for back (reset) button
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCustomerUrl()
    {
        $params = [
            'id' => $this->getCustomerId(),
            'store' => 0
        ];

        return $this->getUrl('stackexchange/stackexchange/customer',$params);
    }

}
```

**//Admin controller**

```
 <?php

    namespace SR\StackExchange\Controller\Adminhtml\Stackexchange;

    use \Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Edit;
    use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

    class Customer extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Edit
    {

        public function execute()
        {
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultPageFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $customer_Id = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            $store = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store');
            $customer = $this->_customerRepository->getById($customer_Id);

            //file_put_contents('Customer.txt', print_r($customer_Id,true), FILE_APPEND);

//Method 1
            //$resultRedirect->setPath('customer/index/edit/',['id' => $customer_Id, 'store' => $store,'_current' => true]);
            //return $resultRedirect;

//Method 2
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
            return $resultRedirect;

        }

    }
```

I have tried 2 different methods, but it's not working for me.

Could you please throw me right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my self to changing the controller method

```
public function execute()
        {
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultPageFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $customer_Id = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            $store = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store');
            $customer = $this->_customerRepository->getById($customer_Id);

            //file_put_contents('Customer.txt', print_r($customer_Id,true), FILE_APPEND);

//Method 1
            //$resultRedirect->setPath('customer/index/edit/',['id' => $customer_Id, 'store' => $store,'_current' => true]);
            //return $resultRedirect;

//Method 2
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
            return $resultRedirect;

        }
```

to

```
public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $customer_Id = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $store = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store');
        $customer = $this->_customerRepository->getById($customer_Id);
        $resultRedirect->setPath('customer/index/edit/',['id' => $customer_Id, 'store' => $store,'_current' => true]);
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
```

Now it's working fine. If some one have better answer feel free to update this.